# Testing LetsEncrypt certificate renewal

Tags: ssl, testing, certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm working on a solution to fetch and renew certificates from Letsencrypt.org automatically. Ironically the normally short lifespan of only three months is a problem for me when it comes to testing renewal.

I am aware of the --force-renew switch, but I'd like to avoid that, because then my test code would differ from my productive code.

Is there a way to tell letsencrypt to issue a test certificate with an even shorter lifespan, say one day? Or is there maybe a way to invalidate a certificate prematurely without incurring side effects? (I'm thinking about revoking, but I fear that may have some unintended consequences I'm not seeing)

Is there maybe some other way to test this in some totally different way I'm not thinking about at all?